# How should I convert a float32 image to an uint8 image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to convert a `float32` image into `uint8` image in Python using the openCV library. I used the following code, but I do not know whether it is correct or not.

Here `I` is the `float32` image.

```
J = I*255
J = J.astype(np.uint8)
```

I really appreciate if can you help me.

Comment: Since no one explicitly said it, so long as your values are between 0 and 1 in your float image, then yes, your code is correct.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to convert an image from single precision floating point (i.e. float32) to uint8, `numpy` and `opencv` in python offers two convenient approaches.

If you know that your image have a range between 0 and 255 or between 0 and 1 then you can simply make the convertion the way you already do:

```
I *= 255 # or any coefficient
I = I.astype(np.uint8)
```

If you don't know the range I suggest you to apply a min max normalization
i.e. : `(value - min) / (max - min)`

With opencv you simply call the following instruction :

```
I = cv2.normalize(I, None, 255, 0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
```

The returned variable I type will have the type `np.uint8` (as specify by the last argument) and a range between 0 and 255.

Using `numpy` you can also write something similar:

```
def normalize8(I):
  mn = I.min()
  mx = I.max()

  mx -= mn

  I = ((I - mn)/mx) * 255
  return I.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: Note that astype truncates decimals.  If you need more accuracy, I recommend changing the last lines to  `I = ((I - mn)/mx) * 255.0` and `return np.round(I).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: It depends what you want to do. For some application it is convinient not to round.
The choice to round is up to the person as well as the application.

Comment: I agree.  That's why I put it as a comment and didn't edit your answer.

Answer (score -6):

It is actually very simple:
`img_uint8 = img_float32.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: downvoted because for an image in range [0,1] this results in an image of 0's which is obviously not an adequate solution.